# R: Knitting error rticles \vadjust in vertical mode

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdftex, rticles

I tried to use the package `rticles` within a Rmd file, in order to generate journal publications. When trying to knit the template as it is, I get following error

```
his is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log UC4_SupplySecurity.log.
! You can't use `\vadjust' in vertical mode.
l.300 \leavevmode\vadjust
                          pre{\hypertarget{ref-Neurobot2013}{}}% 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile UC4_SupplySecurity.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See UC4_SupplySecurity.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Within the log file, the same error is reported:

```
Package pdftex.def Info: UC4_SupplySecurity_files/figure-latex/Figure-1-1.pdf  
used on input line 291.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 241.86113pt x 241.86148pt.
! You can't use `\vadjust' in vertical mode.
l.300 \leavevmode\vadjust
```

I use following configurations

- Latex

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

- R 4.0.5

What am I doing wrong?

Unfortunately I cannot provide a reproductible example, as it corresponds to the raw `Frontiers Journal Article`. The same issue persists with the `Elsevier Journal Article` template.

The template compiles if I remove all references and citations `[@XY]`, but a publication without references is a no-go.

Comment: I had the same problem, I'll check back if I figure anything out.

Comment: I ran into this issue using the latest pandoc release (2.13). Using a previous release (2.11.4) seems to resolve the issue for now. I recognize that isn't a permanent solution, but I couldn't track down the root cause.

Comment: Yep, that version of pandoc works for me too

Comment: I can also reproduce this with `pandoc 2.13`. I _think_ this has something to with how bibliography items are being created in `.tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue with **rticles** has been reported in the Github repo already
https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/383 and it has been fixed in **rticles** 0.20 which is not yet on CRAN.

So for now, one should do

```r
remotes::install_github("rstudio/rticles")
```

Using the dev version, I can render without error the default template for Frontier article.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot knit with code in an \texttt{enumerate} or \texttt{itemize} environment. Maybe this is your problem.

Comment: Could you please paste some code that reproduce the problem? It's unclear now.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error using the default rticles rmarkdown when using pandoc 2.13, although I haven't checked recently if it's been fixed.